# Publish to arm64 not working when cultured resx file added

Tags: visual-studio, publish, arm64, resx

I've created a .Net 6.0 project that uses resx files for localization.
In a Properties folder a Resources.resx file was added (Build action: EmbeddedResource CustomTool: ResxFileCodeGenerator) I was able to publish this to arm-64.
Here is the pubxml file:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\\publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then I add a Resources.nl.resx file into the properties folder (Build action: EmbeddedResource)
When I try to publish now it fails saying that 'arm64' is not a valid setting for option 'platform'
These are the last lines from the output:

> 2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\al.exe /culture:nl /out:obj\Debug\net6.0\linux-arm64\nl\LocalizationResx.resources.dll /platform:arm64 /template:obj\Debug\net6.0\linux-arm64\LocalizationResx.dll /embed:obj\Debug\net6.0\linux-arm64\LocalizationResx.Properties.Resources.nl.resources

> 2>'arm64' is not a valid setting for option 'platform'

The publish works if I set linux-arm as target runtime.

Is this a bug in visual studio? (2022 v17.1.0)

Is there a way to make the publish succesfull?

Is there a better way to do localization for .net 6.0 projects that need to run on an arm64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What fixed the issue for me was opening the csproj file of the executable project and add  `<GenerateSatelliteAssembliesForCore>true</GenerateSatelliteAssembliesForCore>` to the PropertyGroup that contains the targetFramework.

The csProj file of the dummy project looks like this now:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <GenerateSatelliteAssembliesForCore>true</GenerateSatelliteAssembliesForCore>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.nl.resx">
      <Generator></Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The publishing to linux-arm64 is working now